# Rollback em tabela específica Laravel 4

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, artisan

Estou manipulando um banco MySQL com Laravel 4. Quero saber se existe alguma forma de fazer um rollback em apenas uma das tabelas do banco. Por exemplo, a minha migration incluiu as tabelas x, y e z. Quero fazer um rollback apenas na tabela y. É possível?

Comment: Olá @Amanda Lima, sua pergunta não seria sobre truncate? porque a resposta para essa pergunta foi sobre truncate. Se for o caso gostaria de editar sua pergunta. Quando você executa um Rollback ele desfaz apenas a ação executada no momenta, já o truncate limpa a tabela inteira.

Comment: Realmente @MiguelBatista. Não sei se ela está se referindo ao método `down`, presente nas classes de migração do `Laravel`.  Mas, se for para analisar pela resposta data, acho que não tem nada a ver com rollback. Mas lembrando, se estiver falando do método `down` do migrations, então tá certo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim é possível:

Para deletar os dados da tabela:

```
DB::table('tabela_y')->delete();
```

Truncating em uma tabela:

```
DB::table('tabela_y')->truncate();
```

[Link](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#deletes) da documentação.

Comment: Obrigada, não tinha pensado dessa forma! Tem alguma maneira de fazer isso pelo artisan?

Comment: Bem você pode tentar dar um `php artisan tinker` e colocar o comando que postei. Acho que não tem um comando direto para isso.

Comment: Mais uma vez obrigada!

Comment: "Deletar a tabela" ou "Deletar os dados da tabela"?

Comment: Deletar os dados da tabela, corrigi a resposta.